# getting part of the (already rendered) screen as texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, framebuffer, render-to-texture

I'm making an android opengl es 2d app, and trying to use a part of my rendered screen as a texture for a billboard. 
so far, i had partial success with glCopyTexSubImage - it only works on some phones.

everywhere i read recommends using frameBufferObject to render to texture, but i can't grasp how to use it, so if anyone can help me get this, i would thank them greatly.

1. if i use a FBO that is binded to a texture, is it possible to render just part of the screen? if not, isn't that a bit overkill? (also much more work texture mapping and moving the texture. that and the texture would have to be big enough for the part i need to not be blurry)
2. i need to get a snapshot of something that should be rendered to screen anyway, does that mean i have to render my scene twice every frame(one for my texture and another for the actuall render)? am i missing something here?

Comment: What do you mean, "is it possible to render part of the screen?" You can render whatever you want, are you talking about a projection matrix change, or some kind of scissor test, or what exactly?

Comment: Hi, I'll try to explain, 
what i'm trying to get is a 256x256px size texture of my scene at different positions, meaning basically that i need my entire screen rendered as usual, and aside from that, get a 256x256 texture of part of my rendered screen.
i'm assuming a scissor test won't do here because i'll still get my whole screen as the texture, so a projection matrix change will have to do. but still, that means rendering my scene twice - something i'm not so sure i want to do.. so i'm looking for the 'correct' way of doing this..